# Create Array from DIVs then check for similarities

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append

Have to make a form and check if the user write a certain word in textarea. All these words are in arrays created from divs. I got stuck to the verification part, I think I didn't create the arrays in the right way.

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1skw4e2b/) to understand better what I want to make.

```
<select class="items"></select>
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="sport md">
    <p class="word">word1</p>
    <p class="word">word2</p>
    <p class="word">word3</p>
</div>
<div class="culoare md">
    <p class="word">word1</p>
    <p class="word">word2</p>
    <p class="word">word3</p>
</div>

// POpulare selectbox with options
var menu = ['sport', 'culoare'];
var op = '';
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    op += '<option value="' + menu[i] + '">' + menu[i] + '</option>';
}
$('.items').append(op);
$('.items').on('change', function () {
    $('.md.active').removeClass('active');
    var appWords = $('.md.' + $(this).val());
    if (appWords.length) {
        appWords.addClass('active');
    }
});

var array = new Array();
$('.md').each(function () {
    array.push($(this).children());
});
$('textarea').on('keyup', function () {
    console.log(array);
    var key = $(this).val().split(' ');
    console.log(key);
    if (key.indexOf(array) > -1) {
        console.log('match');
    }
});

.md{
    display:none;
}
.md.active{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example, something like "if the user typed xxx the result should be yyy"?
Also, you have a line: if(key.indexOf(array)) , this operation will not work. indexOf takes an array and an element.

Comment: When I run the JS Fiddle, I never see `array` getting populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that your array is not being correctly built. You have an array of paragraph elements. what you are wanting is an array of the text of those paragraph elements. Use the jQuery .map() function for this.

```
var array = $(".md p").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
});
```

You also have an issue with your match comparison at the end. You have 2 arrays. You can't use indexOf to find where the two arrays intersect. Use the jQuery $.grep and $.inArray.

```
var common = $.grep(key, function(element) {
                return $.inArray(element, array ) !== -1;
            });
```

see this update of your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1skw4e2b/1/

Comment: Awesome ! This is what I wanted. Thank you !

Comment: Is there a method to target the element which was writted? I mean i have to counter how many elements from these 3 <p> was writted in the textarea.

Comment: In the code above 'common' is now an array of strings that are common to both the 'key' array and the 'array' array. So to see how many match just use common.length to get the length of the array. to see which words they were just use console.log(common);

Comment: Yes, it is working. It return more then 3 items, can I make something to return only one match for everi item? Now if I will write 3 times the same word it will return 3

Comment: You can use the jquery function "$.unique()" to remove duplicates from the 'common' array. see this updated fiddle line 27 of the javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/1skw4e2b/3/